# Getting 404 response from WebApi route hosted in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sitecore

When I make a call to my custom WebApi route hosted within Sitecore 8.0 I receive a 404 response with an empty body. I've attached the debugger and the controller method does not get called.

I've followed the instructions [here](http://patrickdelancy.com/2013/08/sitecore-webapi-living-harmony/#.V_PsJPkrLRY) to setup a route for a standard WebApi controller hosted within a Sitecore website. My Sitecore configuration consists of Sitecore 8.0 EXM, Experience Analytics, and Experience Extractor. In the AbortSitecoreForKnownRoutes Process method I see the route data is mapped. If I enter an invalid api2 url I get a 404 with a message body which I would expect. There is nothing in the Sitecore logs or the event log that corresponds to this request.

It seems that something is hijacking the request. I've tried patching at the beginning and the end of the httpBeginRequest pipeline to no avail.

I have the following route:

```cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Get By Id Route",
            "api2/{controller}/{id}",
            new { action = "GetById"}
            );
```

Url: http:///ap2/foo/2431243ouidsafj

Controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public class FooController : ApiController
{
     public string GetById(string id)
     {
          return id;
     }
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: what is the routing you are calling and where is your code for the controller declaration?

Comment: http://<hostname>/api2/foo/2342143asdflkas

The controller inherits from ApiController and is declared in in the website project. The code and the route work in a stand asp.net mvc project.

Comment: we have similar routing defined, the only difference I see is that we marked id as an optional parameter.  "RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });". Using /{id} as a part of path sometimes does not work in SC, we usually use parameters via query string parameters.